# How to convert nested array to a parent-child id format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

The api returns data as

```
[
{
    "storageType": "Your Cloud Account",
    "manufacturer": "Oneplus",
    "model": "GM1901",
    "deviceId": "dev-nik-cb41b3fd-21d3-404f-b38f-a9b776e475e3",
    "snapShotView": [
        {
            "itemType": "Folder",
            "name": "11",
            "path": "\\storage\\emulated\\0\\test folder\\11",
            "extension": null,
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "size": "2263521",
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemType": "File",
                    "name": "Eloquent_JavaScript (1).pdf",
                    "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/11/Eloquent_JavaScript (1).pdf",
                    "extension": ".pdf",
                    "modifiedDate": "11/5/2021 2:34:34 PM",
                    "size": "2263521",
                    "items": null,
                    "downloadUri": null
                }
            ],
            "downloadUri": null
        },
        {
            "itemType": "Folder",
            "name": "12",
            "path": "\\storage\\emulated\\0\\test folder\\12",
            "extension": null,
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "size": "583817",
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemType": "File",
                    "name": "Best Sherlock Holmes Ringtone.mp3",
                    "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/12/Best Sherlock Holmes Ringtone.mp3",
                    "extension": ".mp3",
                    "modifiedDate": "11/5/2021 2:34:40 PM",
                    "size": "583817",
                    "items": null,
                    "downloadUri": null
                }
            ],
            "downloadUri": null
        },
        {
            "itemType": "Folder",
            "name": "13",
            "path": "\\storage\\emulated\\0\\test folder\\13",
            "extension": null,
            "modifiedDate": null,
            "size": "269345",
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemType": "File",
                    "name": "The think tank- Manipal wishes you a very.png",
                    "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/13/The think tank- Manipal wishes you a very.png",
                    "extension": ".png",
                    "modifiedDate": "11/5/2021 2:30:06 PM",
                    "size": "229834",
                    "items": null,
                    "downloadUri": null
                },
                {
                    "itemType": "File",
                    "name": "images (4).jpeg",
                    "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/13/images (4).jpeg",
                    "extension": ".jpeg",
                    "modifiedDate": "11/5/2021 2:30:10 PM",
                    "size": "39511",
                    "items": null,
                    "downloadUri": null
                }
            ],
            "downloadUri": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And what I need is

```js
{
  "rootFolderId": "1",
  "storageType": "Your Cloud Account",
  "manufacturer": "Oneplus",
  "model": "GM1901",
  "deviceId": "dev-nik-cb41b3fd-21d3-404f-b38f-a9b776e475e3",
  "fileMap": {
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Main",
      "isDir": true,
      "childrenIds": ["11", "12", "13"],
      "childrenCount": 3
    },
    "11": {
      "id": "11",
      "itemType": "Folder",
      "isDir": true,
      "name": "11",
      "path": "\\storage\\emulated\\0\\test folder\\11",
      "extension": null,
      "modDate": null,
      "size": 2263521,
      "downloadUri": null,
      "childrenIds": ["111"],
      "parentId": ["1"]
    },
    "111": {
      "id": "111",
      "parentId": "11",

      "itemType": "File",
      "name": "Eloquent_JavaScript (1).pdf",
      "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/11/Eloquent_JavaScript (1).pdf",
      "extension": ".pdf",
      "modDate": "11/5/2021 2:34:34 PM",
      "size": 2263521,
      "downloadUri": null
    },

    "12": {
      "id": "12",
      "itemType": "Folder",
      "isDir": true,

      "name": "12",
      "path": "\\storage\\emulated\\0\\test folder\\12",
      "extension": null,
      "modDate": null,
      "size": 583817,
      "childrenIds": ["121"],
      "downloadUri": null,
      "parentId": ["1"]
    },

    "121": {
      "id": "121",
      "parentId": "12",
      "itemType": "File",
      "name": "Best Sherlock Holmes Ringtone.mp3",
      "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/12/Best Sherlock Holmes Ringtone.mp3",
      "extension": ".mp3",
      "modDate": "11/5/2021 2:34:40 PM",
      "size": 583817,
      "items": null,
      "downloadUri": null
    },

    "13": {
      "id": "13",
      "itemType": "Folder",
      "name": "13",
      "isDir": true,

      "path": "\\storage\\emulated\\0\\test folder\\13",
      "extension": null,
      "modDate": null,
      "size": 269345,
      "childrenIds": ["131", "132"],
      "downloadUri": null,
      "parentId": ["1"]
    },

    "131": {
      "id": "131",
      "parentId": "13",
      "itemType": "File",
      "name": "The think tank- Manipal wishes you a very.png",
      "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/13/The think tank- Manipal wishes you a very.png",
      "extension": ".png",
      "modDate": "11/5/2021 2:30:06 PM",
      "size": "229834",
      "items": null,
      "downloadUri": null
    },
    "132": {
      "id": "132",
      "parentId": "13",
      "itemType": "File",
      "name": "images (4).jpeg",
      "path": "/storage/emulated/0/test folder/13/images (4).jpeg",
      "extension": ".jpeg",
      "modDate": "11/5/2021 2:30:10 PM",
      "size": "39511",
      "items": null,
      "downloadUri": null
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to change the nested array to a parentId, ChildrenId format where every child has the ID of its parent element. This is for a file manager app I'm making. I'm confused as to how to do it.

Comment: Hey Nikethan, we are glad to help, but show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. There are multiple ways to handle this, some more efficient than others, but the goal here is to help you overcome issues you are encountering.

Comment: Additionally, please don't add gibberish words/characters to the end of your question. If it didn't let you add the question without it then it did that for a reason and you should respect it. I have edit the question to remove it.

Comment: Hi and thank you, this is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow, will keep that in mind henceforth